# How to change display from default 0,0 position on larger image in Android java

Tags: java, android

i couldnt find an answer to this question, its probably simple..

I have a larger image (world map) on my screen, and i can move horizontally and vertically on map.
The problem is, when i start the activity that shows the map, the default position of the display is 0,0 position so it shows beginning of the picture.

```
_______________
| screen |     |
|________|     |
|              |
|     MAP      |
|______________|

_______________
|      ______  |
|     |screen| |
|     |______| |
|              |
|     MAP      |
|______________|
```

As the picture says, this is what i would like to do, to change default view of display to show itself somewhere else on the map, and i dont know how to do it..

my layout is like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/worldLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".WorldMapActivity" >

    <org.kema.view.VScroll
        android:id="@+id/vScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <org.kema.view.HScroll
            android:id="@+id/hScroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutWorldMap"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewWorldMap"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                    android:contentDescription="World map"
                    android:src="@drawable/contacts_map" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </org.kema.view.HScroll>
    </org.kema.view.VScroll>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how to do that ? Thank you

Edit: just to clarify, my question is not about moving on the screen, i already solved that, its just changing position of default view when you come on the screen.

Comment: Well since noone bothered to help me or didnt know how to, i ve managed to fix the problem and i am working on answering it now..

Answer (score 0):

After world map is drawn, i used vScroll and hScroll to move around the map. U can move with both scrolls with scrollBy() method. Since i didnt find anything usable to change the location of the layout when the layout was created, i was trying to move it by using the scrollBy() method to move the view. THe problem was that i was moving before it was even drawn, so naturally nothing happened.

I managed to solve this like this.
in onCreate you findViewById, and call method that draws a map, in my case drawWorldMap(ImageView). Since i was using scrollBy() in here, before everything was actually drawn, it didnt work. Android first calls onCreateView() by default to create all views, then it calls onCreate(), and after all drawing its done, onCreateView()  is called one more time.

On the last call, everything is ready and you can call scrollBy() to your scroll to actually move the position on the map. So my solution was that after drawWorldMap() was called, i used a boolean to set it on true so i knew that the map was drawn and scrolls were inflated, and after i came back last time in onCreateView() method, i simply checked for the boolean being true and if it was, i moved position of the scroll with scrollBy().

If anyone else encounters any problem i can help him in more detailed code, but since noone seem to have the same problem for now i wont go in too much detail ( code wise).

Have a nice day..